# flex application transparent backbround

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, embed, transparent

i have some problems with embedding swf into html page. Customer asked me to add some round corners to my application. I added. Then the design of the has changed and instead of black background i got ragial gradient(

So, i need to make the corners of the swf transparent, but don't know how.

wmode=transparent and backgroudAlpha param doesn't work. Need some help... :/

It's important that one solution i found works on Flash Builder Beta 2, but didn't work on Adobe flash builder 4.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I worked on a project where we had the same problem. As far as I remember the solution was a combination of setting wmode to transparent, setting backgroundAlpha to 0 and also to set the background color to black.

Comment: No need to set background color to black.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the wmode in html embedding params, and use background alpha = 0 in flash